# substring & instring calculation in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to use substring & instring to extract the required value based on conditions.

I need a specific part if the manager_name column starts with 'Express door%' or 'Express Door%' (D is in captial letter)

and

extract value after **by** for 2 records and for 1 record extract from after **by** and before **','**

Sample code:

```
CREATE TABLE [Test](
service_id int,
category_id int,
employee_name varchar(50)
)

insert into Test values (38756,201830,'kalyan');
insert into Test values (38366,201790,'kalyan');
insert into Test values (38756,201830,'kalyan');
insert into Test values (38366,201790,'kalyan');
insert into Test values (38603,201790,'Ricky');


CREATE TABLE [major](
spec_id int,
manager_name varchar(150)
)

insert into major values (38756,null)
insert into major values (38366,null)
insert into major values (38756,'Express Door for on going : DECLINE by kalyan')
insert into major values (38366,'Express door for on going : APPROVE by Joy kalyan')
insert into major values (38366,'Request required')
insert into major values (38603,'Express door for on going : APPROVE by JRicky, Condtion:test')
```

Below SQL query that I'm using:

```
    select  distinct 
         t.service_id
        ,m.spec_id
       , t.category_id
       , t.employee_name
       , substr(m.manager_name , instr(m.manager_name , 'by') + 3) Manager       
from test t 
left outer join major m on t.service_id = m.spec_id 
where (instr(m.manager_name, 'Express Door') > 0 or instr(m.manager_name, 'Express door') > 0);
```

my expected should be look like below:

```
service_id   category_id       employee_name     manager
38366           201790          kalyan           Joy kalyan
38756           201830          kalyan           kalyan
38603           201790          Ricky            JRicky
```

Thanks in advance

Swetha J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to identify the index of `','` and pass the length of the matching word as third argument for your test scenario.

Also,I have simplified your `WHERE` clause using `INITCAP` function and `LIKE`

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.service_id,
                m.spec_id,
                t.category_id,
                t.employee_name,
                substr(m.manager_name,instr(m.manager_name,'by') + 3,
                    CASE
                     WHEN m.manager_name LIKE '%,%' 
                        THEN instr(m.manager_name,',') 
                                           - (instr(m.manager_name,'by') + 3)
                          ELSE length(m.manager_name)
                                          - (instr(m.manager_name,'by') + 2)
                     END
                ) AS manager
FROM test t
LEFT OUTER JOIN major m ON t.service_id = m.spec_id
WHERE initcap(m.manager_name) LIKE '%Express Door%'
ORDER BY employee_name;
```

As you can see, it gets a little messier with several patterns to match using purely `INSTR` and `SUBSTR`.
We can simplify it using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` although it might be less efficient.

```
select  distinct 
         t.service_id
        ,m.spec_id
       , t.category_id
       , t.employee_name
       , REGEXP_SUBSTR(manager_name,'by(.*?)(,|$)',1,1,null,1) as  manager
from test t 
left outer join major m on t.service_id = m.spec_id 
where initcap(m.manager_name) like  '%Express Door%'
ORDER by employee_name;
```

`by(.*?)(,|$)` - matches `by` followed by a set of words (names) before finding a comma or end of line. `.*?` is for non-greedy match.

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=548446a4626581e6e36714ee3e0220ff)